# SAPUI5 Access Component from MyUtils

Tags: model, sapui5

I define a global model and would like to access this from a util method.

```
var oAppModel = new JSONModel({
    isLoading: false
});
oAppModel.setDefaultBindingMode("OneWay");
this.setModel(oAppModel, "appModel");
```

And here is my util Class

```
sap.ui.define([], function() {
   "use strict";

   return {
      myFunc: function(input) {
         // ==> try to get Data from the app Model
      }
   };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a global model, you can do the following:

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oAppModel, "appModel");
---
sap.ui.getCore().getModel("appModel");
```

But the global variables/models are not a good things, I'd use them only in very rare and specific cases.